# Why is this time.set only waiting for 0.9 seconds once?

Tags: python

```
import pygame

obstacle_timer = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(obstacle_timer, 900)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    if event.type == obstacle_timer:
        obstacle_rect_list.append(snail_surf.get_rect(midbottom = (randint(900,1100),300)))
```

This is all the code that have something to do with the time.set.
It is only waiting 0.9 seconds once.

Comment: Please read about [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). `if event.type == obstacle_timer:` needs to be in the event loop, not after the event loop.

Comment: `if event.type == obstacle_timer` That line is not part of the `while True` loop.  Is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi check the updated code, Your indentation was wrong in second if statement.

```
import pygame
    
    obstacle_timer = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    pygame.time.set_timer(obstacle_timer, 900)
    
    while True:
    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            if event.type == obstacle_timer:
                obstacle_rect_list.append(snail_surf.get_rect(midbottom(randint(900,1100),300)))
```